# Unspecified Error when search a table for a string in sql delphi using parameters - Delphi SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-like, prepared-statement, unspecified

there. I am trying to search for a string contained in any column of a sql table by adding all the Fieldnames to the WHERE clause using a for loop. Also I use parameters to protect against SQL injection. But when I run I get an error like this:

> Unspecified error

How can this be fixed and what is the problem (Not necessarily in that order). Here is my code. I am running Delphi 7

```
procedure TfrmView.edtSearchChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, i2: integer;
  obj: TEdit;
  QueryText: string;
begin
  obj:= Sender as TEdit;

  with dmInfo do
    begin
      qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
      qryInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
      qryInfo.Open;

      tblInfo.SQL.Clear;
      tblInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
      tblInfo.SQL.Add('WHERE (' + qryInfo.Fields[0].FieldName + ' LIKE :SQuery0)');
      QueryText:= '%' + obj.Text + '%';
      tblInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SQuery0').Value:= QueryText;
      ShowMessage(QueryText);
      ShowMessage(tblInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SQuery0').Value);
      for i:= 1 to qryInfo.FieldCount - 1 do
        begin
          tblInfo.SQL.Add(' OR (' + qryInfo.Fields[i].FieldName + ' LIKE :SQuery' + IntToStr(i) + ')');
          tblInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SQuery' + IntToStr(i)).Value:= '%' + obj.Text + '%';
        end;
    tblInfo.Open;
end;
```

Comment: You've confused `Field.FieldName` and `Field.Value` again. When setting parameter values, you want to use the field's **content**, not the field's **name**. You really should learn to actually read the code you're writing.

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong code. Was gonna write the question yesterday but only wrote it today. I edited the question's code. Same error as before @KenWhite

Comment: Place a TMemo on your form and, before you call tblInfo.Open, copy tblInfo.Sql.Text into it.  I suspect you will see your error.

Comment: Move your ShowMessage down to just above your `tblInfo.Open`. (We just went through this Friday, didn't we?)

Comment: Ok I did that. Everything looks normal, but should the output look like this: SELECT * FROM tblGymnast WHERE (GymnastID LIKE :SQuery0) OR (Surname LIKE :SQuery1) OR ..... Goes on like that. Should SQuery be displayed and not the value it is holding?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The replacement is done when the query is executed.

Comment: Ok but still giving error tho. What do I do?

Comment: If I remember correctly, not all of the columns you're querying are text (you have some numeric columns). You can't use `LIKE` on any data type but text (CHAR/VARCHAR).

Comment: No, all my columns are text, I changed it all to text.

Comment: You changed your database to make all of the table columns text?

Comment: Do you perhaps need a space before `WHERE`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: No. Using SQL.Add adds a CR at the end of the line, so there's no missing space.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Ken - news to me.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `SQL` is just a `TStrings` property. `TStrings.Add` has always added a line break. One of the main purposes of it. I'm rather surprised a developer with such experience would not know this.

Comment: What you're doing is extremely atypical. (Certainly changing all columns to char/varchar just so you can do this dodgy search is an ill-conceived hack!) Ordinarily, when binding parameters of a query, you know in advance how many parameters there are. So you can try making your code flow a little more "conventional": First add up your parameters (_without setting any values_); and only when all have been added, then set all the values.

Comment: I would try to first build the entire SQL statement and only then assign parameters values (I do not have Delphi now, so I can't check). also to get filed names of the table you could use SCHEMA information from the connection object or at-least use `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=0` so it wont fetch ALL records just to know the table fields,

Comment: Also, You must use LIKE only with text type columns as @Ken wrote. so you need to check the field data type in the loop when you construct the SQL and parameters values.

Comment: If you want us to help you, please [edit] your post to provide the DDL (CREATE TABLE) statement, some sample data for that table, and include a tag for the DBMS (database) you're using. This speculating about what you might or might not have done or what you can *try* to see if it works us useless. Provide the details we need to help, by making an [edit] to the question to do so, instead of posting in comments..

Answer (score -1):

The whole code makes no sense.

- You let the code run every time you change a letter.
  run by an onChange event
- five input/letter to the edtSearch input field means the code is executed five times without interruption immediately
- If you delete all content in the edtSearch input field at once,
  which is also a change event.
  This time it runs with an **empty** edtSearch.text
- How can you expect that this works without exceptions
- You open each time two tables without to close them before.
- you are using a variable, which suggests that this event is also
  connected to other TEdits.

  obj: TEdit;
     obj:= Sender as TEdit;
- You clear the SQL on an open table.
- you have two tables the first one does nothing more than SQL.clear
  and open
- You're using fields from first table and create the SQL for second table
- Even if both tables are the same, it makes no sense to use the fields
  from the first table.
  It is confusing, misleading and unnecessary.

**First of all remove the code out of the onChange event**

What you want to do with this code
to search for values on all fields from the `tblInfo`
can be done without the first tabel `qryInfo`

**you do not need to increment the params.**

Do not create the params all the time from `SQuery1` to maybe `SQuery100`

if you only use one param (the search value is always the same)
You can set all params with a single use `tblInfo.Parameters.ParamByName()` before the `tblInfo.Open`
but NOT in the loop.

This will replace all params `:SQuery` all at once with the value

SQL.Text :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE (IDmember LIKE :SQuery)
OR (memberName LIKE :SQuery)
OR (petName LIKE :SQuery)
OR (Address LIKE :SQuery)
```

---

**Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement**

Is different from database to database

**How many OR clauses can I use in a single WHERE condition in MySql query?**

I know there was a limit in the past.
But now the experts knowledge is different

only one of the opinions

> The truth is that it's limited to the resources available on the
>   database, the size of the data set in question, the indexes being
>   addressed (or lack thereof) and the complexity of each clause.
>
> If your goal is to find a person record that meets multiple criteria,
>   I am willing to bet you won't run in to a limit. You could easy OR
>   condition with 20 to 30 conditions and no user is going to provide
>   more that that / person records won't have more than one that meets
>   that many conditions.

Comment: Do you understand how the `Parameters` object works?

Comment: I know it's not working right at **any position** in the query. Also using a quoted value on a (int) field. I also found out you can not place **:xyzParam** at any place in a query. In the past I have much problems until I found out I can use params most like `WHERE member_name = :xyzparam`  thats a good place .

Comment: DV removed. This answer is now helpful and more relevant. If OP implements your suggestions, it will certainly be an improvement; though it's unclear whether this will fix his specific problem.